# how can i annotate a single quote mark when i use Imagick::annotateImage()?

Tags: php

If I annotate a single quote mark on a image, I will output like this: `I\'m cool`

```
$status = $this->_im->annotateImage($this->_draw, 0, 0, $options['angle'], $text);
```

who can help me? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably caused by [`magic_quotes_gpc`](http://php.net/magic_quotes). You can remove the escaped quote using [`stripslashes`](http://php.net/stripslashes):

```
$status = $this->_im->annotateImage(
    $this->_draw, 
    0,
    0,
    $options['angle'], 
    stripslashes($text)
);
```

You *can* reconfigure your server to disable magic quotes if you wish, but if you're working on an existing website, I wouldn't necessarily recommend that until you fully understand the implications of doing so and feel confident in your ability to safely sanitise any data you use in database queries.